# Convert between signed char & unsigned char representing UTF8

Tags: c++, c, utf-8

I am using libxml2 and ICU in the same project. They represent
UTF8 differently.  libxml2 uses unsigned char*, and ICU constructors take in plain char* (which on my Pentium 64-bit is equivalent to signed char).

Question: how do I convert between the two?  Can I just
use static_cast?

I understand that UTF8 only cares that the underlying data
type be at least 8 bits long. Both signed char and unsigned
char satisfy this.  I am just wondering if there is any
gotcha here?  Any corner cases?

EDIT: at my compiler's (g++/Gentoo) insistence, only reinterpret_cast can do this conversion (without relying on the C-style cast).  Let's say we have two unsigned char strings: 0000 and 1000.  The conversion will turn them both into 0.  Is this possible under UTF8?

Comment: It seems to me that, "yes, in this case, the sign doesn't matter."  Both of these approaches are obviously treating the data 'byte-by-byte.'  (In other words, "neither of them are 'multi-byte aware' ...)  Therefore, "it's a difference that makes no difference."  From the point-of-view of the digital computer, at least in this case ... "a byte is a byte is a byte."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all.  Mike said it best: the difference that makes no difference, and "a byte is a byte is a byte".

Answer (score 3):

Some libraries use `char` for storing UTF-8, others use `unsigned char`.

In this case you may need to cast between `char*` and `unsigned char*` using `reinterpret_cast`, since these types have the same storage unit size and alignment. E.g.:

```
char const* s = ...;
unsigned char const* p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const*>(s);
```

`static_cast` can always simulate `reinterpret_cast` through an intermediate conversion to `void*`, e.g. `char* -> void* -> unsigned char*`, e.g.:

```
char const* s = ...;
void const* intermediate = s;
unsigned char const* p = static_cast<unsigned char const*>(intermediate);
```

Comment: Thanks, Maxim - it appears that my compiler (g++/Gentoo) insists on reinterpret_cast and rejects static_cast for this particular conversion.  The only quibble then is how to deal with +0/-0 phenomenon where, e.g., both 0000 and 1000 unsigned chars will, via 2's comp, become +0 and -0, respectively, after conversion.  Reading the UTF8 standard, I'm starting to think that 1000 is not a valid byte sequence, though I might be mistaken.  That's one of the corner cases I had in mind initially.

Comment: You only have +0 and -0 in one's compliment representation.

Answer (score 0):

If unsigned char* is just a pointer to a string it should not cause any problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should not matter. In any case as soon as you need to extract a char from the char * or unsigned char * stream you will need a function provided by the library that will extract an int and update the pointer/iterator in a manner that is opaque to you (the caller)